# Beautify JSON parsing with Hashie::Mash Rash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Trying to parse some ugly JSON:

```
image = product.images.find { |i| i["sizeName"] == "Large" }
```

If I use [Hashie::Mash Rash](https://github.com/tcocca/rash), can I make it look like this instead?

```
image = product.images.find { |i| i["size_name"] == "large" }
```

If so, why am I getting `undefined method 'each_pair' for #<Array:0x007f84a0408540>`? Please see https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/6b8012f9197ca6c675a9 for a full example including a live app.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "category": {
            "id": "women",
            "name": "Women's Fashion"
        },
        "showSizeFilter": false,
        "showColorFilter": true,
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 20,
        "total": 974184
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 377083005,
            "name": "BCBGeneration Women's Contrast Sleeve Trench",
            "currency": "USD",
            "price": 168,
            "priceLabel": "$168.00",
            "salePrice": 106.43,
            "salePriceLabel": "$106.43",
            "inStock": true,
            "retailer": {
                "id": "849",
                "name": "Amazon.com",
                "url": "http://www.shopstyle.com/browse/Amazon.com-US?pid=uid9616-726296-93"
            },
            "locale": "en_US",
            "description": "This jacket features contrasting leather sleeves",
            "brand": {
                "id": "51",
                "name": "BCBG MAX AZRIA",
                "url": "http://www.shopstyle.com/browse/BCBG-MAX-AZRIA?pid=uid9616-726296-93"
            },
            "clickUrl": "http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiVisitRetailer?id=377083005&pid=uid9616-726296-93",
            "images": [
                {
                    "sizeName": "Small",
                    "width": 32,
                    "height": 40,
                    "url": "http://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/7b/28/7b2894c203529b0956cdd6b760629d4a_small.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "sizeName": "Medium",
                    "width": 112,
                    "height": 140,
                    "url": "http://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/7b/28/7b2894c203529b0956cdd6b760629d4a_medium.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "sizeName": "Large",
                    "width": 164,
                    "height": 205,
                    "url": "http://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/7b/28/7b2894c203529b0956cdd6b760629d4a.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "colors": [
                {
                    "name": "Chino"
                }
            ],
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "name": "XX-Small"
                },
                {
                    "name": "X-Small"
                }
            ],
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "raincoats-and-trenchcoats",
                    "name": "Raincoats & Trenchcoats"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please post some piece of `JSON` what you try parse.

Comment: Sure thing! Here we go: https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/90dfced310a017d1f354

Comment: Absolutely. All done! :)

Comment: @MarkBoulder I copy this json and paste to http://jsonlint.com or via JSON.parse(). it doesn't seem to be a valid json. Can you try to get a valid one?

Comment: It is now valid. Note that my first example works - I'm just wondering if I can make things more Rubyesque using Rash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my working code

```
require 'json'
require 'rash'

@json_text = <<END
{
    "metadata": {
        "category": {
            "id": "women",
            "name": "Women's Fashion"
        },
        "showSizeFilter": false,
        "showColorFilter": true,
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 20,
        "total": 974184
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 377083005,
            "name": "BCBGeneration Women's Contrast Sleeve Trench",
            "currency": "USD",
            "price": 168,
            "priceLabel": "$168.00",
            "salePrice": 106.43,
            "salePriceLabel": "$106.43",
            "inStock": true,
            "retailer": {
                "id": "849",
                "name": "Amazon.com",
                "url": "http://www.shopstyle.com/browse/Amazon.com-US?pid=uid9616-726296-93"
            },
            "locale": "en_US",
            "description": "This jacket features contrasting leather sleeves",
            "brand": {
                "id": "51",
                "name": "BCBG MAX AZRIA",
                "url": "http://www.shopstyle.com/browse/BCBG-MAX-AZRIA?pid=uid9616-726296-93"
            },
            "clickUrl": "http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiVisitRetailer?id=377083005&pid=uid9616-726296-93",
            "images": [
                {
                    "sizeName": "Small",
                    "width": 32,
                    "height": 40,
                    "url": "http://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/7b/28/7b2894c203529b0956cdd6b760629d4a_small.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "sizeName": "Medium",
                    "width": 112,
                    "height": 140,
                    "url": "http://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/7b/28/7b2894c203529b0956cdd6b760629d4a_medium.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "sizeName": "Large",
                    "width": 164,
                    "height": 205,
                    "url": "http://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/7b/28/7b2894c203529b0956cdd6b760629d4a.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "colors": [
                {
                    "name": "Chino"
                }
            ],
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "name": "XX-Small"
                },
                {
                    "name": "X-Small"
                }
            ],
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "raincoats-and-trenchcoats",
                    "name": "Raincoats & Trenchcoats"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
END

hash = JSON.parse(@json_text)

@rash = Hashie::Rash.new( hash )


images = []
@rash.products.each do |product|
   images << product.images.find { |i| i.size_name.downcase == "large" }
end


puts images.inspect
#[#<Hashie::Rash height=205 size_name="Large" url="http://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/7b/28/7b2894c203529b0956cdd6b760629d4a.jpg" width=164>]
```

It doesn't raise the error you have mentioned.

And I use

```
$ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
gem list --local |grep 'rash'
rash (0.4.0)
$gem list --local |grep  'hashie'
hashie (3.2.0, 2.0.5)
```

Could you check yours?

And, if possible, dump the json at the moment that it raises the error.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. How do you manage to run the above code without creating a new application? I tried pasting it into `rails console` but it just went bonkers. Anyway this would be my testcase: https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/cd5a6ca61bf5da3d9aa8

Comment: Here's the full example: https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/11058955 -- which produces `undefined method 'each_pair' for #<Array:0x000000032da8b8>`

Comment: Sure thing! Preferably the first one though.

Comment: If so, please add me 'zdk' to the gist.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to add you. You could just fork it maybe?

Comment: Turned out I had to map the arrays into hashes before it would work: https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/11058955

Comment: the 'products' key is already an array. So, why do you need to map like that? and Why don't you simply use `raw = JSON.parse(response); rash.products.each{}` like the one I illustrated? just curious.

Comment: Apparently Rash only works for hashes. See live app at http://runnable.com/U-GxN6uPAY5P0Ruo/td-rash.

Comment: What do you think, could it be improved somehow?

Comment: Just tested it on Runnable. I think you are confused on something, I'm not sure what. But I'm sure this problem is really simple and straightforward thing to solve. The way you have done is not natural and add unnecessary logic which will make your app slower later. Please see my comment at https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/11058955#comment-1276344

Comment: Thanks a lot man. To think that your solution is superior to one of the Rash contributors is kinda cool.